# Aggregate histogram data

Tags: r, histogram

I have the histogram for a number of properties of different unique models of some 'thing'. 
When I do an experiment I find multiple of those unique models. I need to find the histogram of each property considering the entire sample set of the experiment.

Example:

With a data frame `df` like below, with a bunch of `id's` and for each `id` there are a bunch of properties named `prop1`, `prop2` and so on.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:5, 6, replace = TRUE),
                     prop1 = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                     prop2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 6, replace = TRUE),
                     prop3=sample(3:6, 6, replace = TRUE))

> df
  id prop1 prop2 prop3
1  2     A FALSE     4
2  2     B  TRUE     4
3  3     A FALSE     6
4  1     B  TRUE     5
5  3     A FALSE     3
6  3     B FALSE     4
```

For eqch unique `id` a histogram is computed for each property and the result is stored in a list `l1` which holds the histogram for each property on a per `id` basis.

```
# Create histogram for each property
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.factor)
fun1 <- function(df, n){as.data.frame(t(sapply(split(df, df$id), function(i) 
                                                         prop.table(table(i[,n])))))}
l1 <- sapply(2:ncol(df), function(i)fun1(df, i))
names(l1) <- names(df[-1])

> l1
$prop1
          A         B
1 0.0000000 1.0000000
2 0.5000000 0.5000000
3 0.6666667 0.3333333

$prop2
  FALSE TRUE
1   0.0  1.0
2   0.5  0.5
3   1.0  0.0

$prop3
          3         4 5         6
1 0.0000000 0.0000000 1 0.0000000
2 0.0000000 1.0000000 0 0.0000000
3 0.3333333 0.3333333 0 0.3333333
```

Now below I have a new set of `ids` from a new experiment, with repetitions. I need to compute the histogram for each property across the set of `id's` using the reference data from `l1`.

Some `id's` may not be present; some `id's` not present in the original `df` and `l1` may be present in `ids`- example `4` in `ids` is not present in `l1` - however these can be excluded from the histogram computation , but captured as a dataframe with excluded `id` and count for each `id` excluded.

```
ids <- sample(1:4, 7, replace = TRUE)
> ids
 [1] 2 3 1 3 3 2 4
```

**Update:**
Expected output - I'm showing it as a list-  any other data structure which is more appropriate could be used.

```
> l2
$prop1
      A     B
1 0.500 0.500

$prop2
    FALSE    TRUE
1   0.667  0.333

$prop3
      3     4     5     6
1 0.167 0.500 0.167 0.167
```

base R solution preferred.

**Update**: Clarifying how the output is computed.

Counts in `ids` - one 1, two 2, three 3 and one 4. Since we do not have any data for 4 the useful `ids` are 1, 2 and 3 with total count of 6 `ids` between them.

For `prop1`, the aggregated histogram for `ids` can be computed as follows

```
A = (1*0.0 + 2*0.5  + 3*0.6667)/6 = 0.5
B = (1*1.0 + 2*0.5  + 3*0.3333)/6 = 0.5
```

Comment: your new dataset is going to have a different histogram right? so do you want to re-normalize your `prop.table` w.r.t. the new data? can you include expected output?

Comment: @SandipanDey - added expected output

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for you, that does involve other packages (`dplyr` and `tidyr`). Since I am reshaping (melting) the data that you generated in a list. After that I spread the data into a nice data.frame. Offcourse you could also use the normalized version of the data. (`df`) within `function(x)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- do.call(rbind,
               lapply(ids, function(id) do.call(cbind,
                                                lapply(names(l1),function(x) {
  df <- l1[[x]] %>% rownames_to_column("id")
  df <- df[df$id == id,] %>% gather(key, value, -id) 
  if(nrow(df) > 0){
    df[,'key'] <- paste0(x,'.',df[,'key'])
    df <- df %>% spread(key,value)
  }
  df
}))
)
)
```

result:

```
> res
  id   prop1.A   prop1.B id prop2.FALSE prop2.TRUE id   prop3.4   prop3.5 prop3.6
1  2 0.6666667 0.3333333  2   0.6666667  0.3333333  2 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
2  3 1.0000000 0.0000000  3   1.0000000  0.0000000  3 0.0000000 0.0000000       1
3  2 0.6666667 0.3333333  2   0.6666667  0.3333333  2 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
4  2 0.6666667 0.3333333  2   0.6666667  0.3333333  2 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
5  2 0.6666667 0.3333333  2   0.6666667  0.3333333  2 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
```

You can also achieve this without your `prop.table` function and only `dplyr` which is a much neater solution.

```
propsum <- df %>% gather(key,value,-id) %>% mutate(n = 1) %>%
  complete(nesting(key,value),id, fill=list(n = 0)) %>%
  group_by(id, key, value) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(id, key) %>%
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)
         ,col = paste0(key,'.',value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, col, p) %>%
  spread(col,p)

propsum[match(ids,propsum$id),]
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 8
      id   prop1.A   prop1.B prop2.FALSE prop2.TRUE   prop3.4   prop3.5 prop3.6
   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1      2 0.6666667 0.3333333   0.6666667  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
2     NA        NA        NA          NA         NA        NA        NA      NA
3     NA        NA        NA          NA         NA        NA        NA      NA
4     NA        NA        NA          NA         NA        NA        NA      NA
5      3 1.0000000 0.0000000   1.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000       1
6     NA        NA        NA          NA         NA        NA        NA      NA
7      2 0.6666667 0.3333333   0.6666667  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
8      2 0.6666667 0.3333333   0.6666667  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
9     NA        NA        NA          NA         NA        NA        NA      NA
10     2 0.6666667 0.3333333   0.6666667  0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667       0
```

---

Since you added the **expected result**, I am not sure in what way this result was generated. I give you two options:

**option 1**: using the source data to multiply according to the given ids.

```
#option 1       
data.frame(id = ids) %>% inner_join(df, by='id') %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  complete(nesting(key,value),id, fill=list(n = 0)) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(p = n/sum(n))
```

which results in:

```
    key value     n          p
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 prop1     A     9 0.69230769
2 prop1     B     4 0.30769231
3 prop2 FALSE     9 0.69230769
4 prop2  TRUE     4 0.30769231
5 prop3     4     4 0.30769231
6 prop3     5     8 0.61538462
7 prop3     6     1 0.07692308
```

or **option 2**:
Using the aggregated data and calculate the mean proportion.

```
#option 2
df %>% gather(key,value,-id) %>% mutate(n = 1) %>%
  complete(nesting(key,value),id, fill=list(n = 0)) %>%
  group_by(id, key, value) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  group_by(id, key) %>%
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)) %>%
  inner_join(data.frame(id = ids), by='id') %>% 
  group_by(key, value) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(p))
```

which results in:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: key [?]

    key value         p
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 prop1     A 0.7333333
2 prop1     B 0.2666667
3 prop2 FALSE 0.7333333
4 prop2  TRUE 0.2666667
5 prop3     4 0.2666667
6 prop3     5 0.5333333
7 prop3     6 0.2000000
```

Comment: +1! If you go down the `dplyr` route, I would use `bind_cols` and `bind_rows` in stead of `do.call(rbind, cbind)`. And I also dislike having nested apply loops, but I can't provide you with an alternative quickly :).

Comment: I have altered the answer and addes a neater solution. The wrong rows were selected in my first solution (rownumber instead of rowname).

Comment: @Wietze314 - the output expected is histogram for `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3` and so on considering the new set of `id's` - updated the question with expected output.

Comment: @Wietze314 - I added some notes on how the output is computed

Comment: Then you can go with **option 2**